# How can I index a self-referential object?

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

For example, `Exception` contains a reference to itself inside `Exception.InnerException`. I have a class like this that I want to index but `var fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<DTO>();` throws a StackoverflowException. How can I index this object?

So far my only idea is to put `[FieldBuilderIgnore]` on the reference and manually submit each object by crawling the the references but that doesn't sound right and I don't know what implications it would have on searchability.

Comment: I'm surprised about the StackOverflowException -- What version of the SDK are you using? The failure mode should be more graceful than that.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Hi Bruce, I'm referencing 10.1.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Search.Data and Microsoft.Azure.Search.Service from a .net core 2.1 app.

Comment: I've created a GitHub issue to track the less-than-graceful failure here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a self-referential field in Azure Cognitive Search; There is no way to express such a field in the index definition. Complex fields in the index are defined by structure and not by type, so sub-field relationships imply containment rather than reference.